# Problema al sacar valores de un array, laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

tengo el siguiente array, que llega a mi vista.

```
array:5 [▼
   0 => {#372 ▼
   +"usuario_ad": "Hector Bernal"
   +"count(usuario_ad)": 3
  }
  1 => {#369 ▼
   +"usuario_ad": "Juli Loa"
   +"count(usuario_ad)": 2
  }
  2 => {#366 ▼
    +"usuario_ad": "raul"
    +"count(usuario_ad)": 1
  }
 3 => {#411 ▼
    +"usuario_ad": "roberto"
    +"count(usuario_ad)": 1
  }
  4 => {#417 ▼
    +"usuario_ad": "Thor"
    +"count(usuario_ad)": 2
  }
]
```

El problema es, que en mi codigo html.

```
    <thead>
        <th>Usuario</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
                @if(count($data))

                @foreach($data as $dat)
                   <tr>
                      <td>{{$dat->usuario_ad}}</td>
                      <td>{{$dat->count(usuario_ad)}}</td>
                 </tr>
              @endforeach  
           @else
           <tr>
            <td colspan="8">No hay registro !!</td>
          </tr>
          @endif
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </td></tr>
```

se como extraer el primer valor que es usuario_ad, pero no se como extraer el segundo campo "count(usuario_ad)", ya que si lo extraigo asi, me aparece este error.

> "Call to undefined method stdClass::count()"

como debo extraer ese tipo de valor que aparece con `count(usuario_ad)`?

Comment: y si en la consulta a `count(usuario_ad)` le pones un alias así: `count(usuario_ad) as conteo` y después en tu vista tratas de recuperar la propiedad `conteo` ?

Comment: :D perfecto, gracias aprendiz por dedicar tiempo a estas preguntas novatas

Comment: Cómo estás haciendo la consulta? Porque existe el [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la consulta a:

```
count(usuario_ad)
```

le pones un alias así:

```
count(usuario_ad) as conteo
```

y después en tu vista tratas de recuperar la propiedad conteo así:

```
<td>{{$dat->conteo}}</td>
```

Comment: Exacto.. funciono!